# git rebase; how to fast-forward

Tags: git

I'm confused about this situation.

I basically develop alone, but sometime my teammate add some feature.
So I made a develop branch.(It's still beta phase, so I don't want to merge `add-subscripiton` branch to `develop`.)

I'd love to make 'develop' branch catch up with`add-subscription` branch.

I could do something like

```
git checkout develop
git rebase add-subscription
```

However this messes the history up.
How can I work around?

[image]

Comment: Do the two branches have a common ancestor? What do you mean by messing up the history? It should bring all commits of the other branch. Is it not the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

If you want all commits of `add-subscription` in `develop` you can do

```
git checkout develop
git merge add-subscription
```

which keeps `develop` up-to-date with `add-subscription` but leaves `add-subscription` untouched.

If you only want certain (but not all) commits from `add-subscription` in `develop` you can use

```
git checkout develop
git cherry-pick <commit>...
```

Both methods (in contrast to `rebase`) do not change history.